# If a sequence of functions tends to infinity pointwise, does it also tend to infinity uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Im trying to prove a variation of Harnack's theorem want to show that a sequence of positive harmonic functions $h_n:G\to \mathbb{R}$ diverge locally uniformly to infinity if they diverge to infinity pointwise.

For a fixed $w$ I have deduced this inequality:
$$\tau_G(z,w)^{-1}h_n(w)\leq h(z)$$ where the the Harnack distance $\tau_G(z,w)$ is defined as the smallest number such that $\tau_G(z,w)^{-1}h(w)\leq h(z)\leq \tau_G(z,w)h(w)$ for all positive harmonic functions $h$ on $G$.
so if we assume that $h_n(w)\to \infty$ does that mean $h(z)\to \infty$ locally uniformly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "locally uniform convergence to $+\infty$"?

Comment: @mrf $(h_n)$ tends uniformly to $\infty$ if for all $a\in G$ there exists $r>0$ such that $\overline{K(a,r)}\subseteq G$ and $h_n(z)\to \infty$ for all $z\in \overline{K(a,r)}$

Comment: *Locally uniformly i ment*